# How does WordPress know if a URL doesn't exist?

Tags: search, 404-error

The WordPress theme I am using didn't come with a proper Error 404 handler and I'd like to add one to the code. I am having a hard time how WordPress determines if a URL does exist as a post, is a search query, or doesn't exist. I'd like to know where the code WordPress uses is located, or how WordPress determines this as I need to implicate it in the theme files.

Comment: you don't really need to know how WordPress determines this, you just need to add a `404.php` template to your theme.

Comment: Do I need to add anything specific to the top of the file or is it straight up PHP @Milo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add anything special to the top of 404.php. WordPress will know to use 404.php automatically when it tries to get a post or page and fails.

To create a custom 404 page for a theme, the simplest way is to:

1. Copy the index.php file from the current theme to a file called 404.php.
2. Edit your new 404.php to delete the code dealing with displaying posts/pages and comments (basically, remove 'The Loop' but leave the header, main div structure, sidebar, footer).
3. Replace the part you deleted with the HTML/PHP you'd like to display in its place (404: Sorry, ***_*___** cannot be found).

I **highly** recommend taking a look at the 404.php that comes with the TwentyTwelve, TwentyThirteen (etc.) themes to get a grasp of how WordPress 404 error pages work.

I've never personally had a problem with WordPress being unable to tell a URL doesn't exist, but if you want to make absolutely *sure* your web server returns your custom 404.php when a page can't be found, add the following line to .htaccess in the main folder where index.php is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
```

Just change the URL accordingly if you have WordPress installed in a subdirectory.

I hope this helps a little. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! My theme is written oddly (what usually is 'header.php' and 'footer.php') where all the functions were in the index.php file- so I had to figure out how he wrote it to make the 404.php template. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to customize the 404's core.

One theme always has a file 404.php. You can do normally everything and display in this page
(Get some post, images,link, tag....).

If you want add a hook, try this: [Are there any hooks that alter the 404 logic?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/are-there-any-hooks-that-alter-the-404-logic)

Good luck.