# Intentionally exceed max_num_pages on main query without getting 404?

Tags: wp-query, pagination, 404-error

In author.php I have two loops: the default *main loop* that gets all posts from that author, and another custom *WP_Query* called `$secondloop`. Both queries have `posts_per_page` set to **3**. Now I'd like to **paginate both query results**.

For this I've added an argument to `$secondloop = new WP_Query($args)`:

```
"paged" => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

(read: set this query's page to the same page as the *main query's*).

## THE PROBLEM:

- If the *main loop* gives me 5 posts and my `$secondloop` gives me 2, then calling **page 2** works no problemo. It shows me the remaining 2 posts from the *main loop* and none from my `$secondloop` (since it doesn't go inside `while ($secondloop->have_posts())`).
- **BUT** if the *main loop* has 2 posts and `$secondloop` has 5, then calling **page 2** results in **404** :(
  I obviously want `$secondloop`'s remaining 2 posts instead.

Changing anything inside the author.php template doesn't help, because it seems that no PHP code in there is executed any more, once WordPress detects that `max_num_pages` from the *main loop* is exceeded.

**How can I "override" that behaviour?**

---

## THE CODE:

**author.php** (just the useful bit)

```
<?php if (have_posts()) { ?>
    <div class="row archive-grid">
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            include(locate_template('parts/loop-archive-grid.php'));
            endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php }

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$secondloop = new WP_Query(array(
    "post_type"      => "musikalbum",
    "posts_per_page" => 3,
    "author_name"    => get_query_var('author_name'),
    "paged"          => $paged
));

if ($secondloop->have_posts()) { ?>
    <div class="row archive-grid">
        <?php while ($secondloop->have_posts()) : $secondloop->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'album-grid' );
        endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php author_page_navi( $loop );
} else {
    joints_page_navi();
} ?>
```

Setting the `posts_per_page` for my *main query* in my **functions.php**

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
    if (is_author()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    } else {
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 9);
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

---

## EDIT: ATTEMPT 1

Milo pointed me to an answer that suggested to add this to my **functions.php**:

```
function my_404_override() {
  global $wp_query;

  if (is_author()) {
    status_header( 200 );
    $wp_query->is_404 = false;
  }
}
add_filter('template_redirect', 'my_404_override');
```

But it still shows me a 404 error. If I remove the if clause, then it leads me to the index.php which is not reeeally what I intended. So I need that if clause...but WordPress doesn't seem to know it yet!

Pasting the code directly to the template didn't work either, even if it's just these three lines before `get_header();`:

```
global $wp_query;
status_header( 200 );
$wp_query->is_404 = false;
```

---

## EDIT: ATTEMPT 2

I ditched `template_redirect` for hooking into `pre_get_posts`:

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
    if (is_author()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
      // NEW CODE:
      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? intval(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
      global $original_page_request; // saves the original value of $paged because I'm about to alter it!
      if ($paged > $query->max_num_pages) {
        $query->set('paged', $query->max_num_pages);
        $original_page_request = $paged;
    } else {
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 9);
    }
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

The idea was to manually reset `paged` for the *main query* when it exceeds `max_num_pages` and store the "actual page" in `global $original_page_request` for my `$secondloop` to set its `paged` parameter to. **Unfortunately though, it doesn't work.** I was so happy not to see a 404 any more, but now it automatically sets the *main query* page to 0. *Why 0?!*

Because in `pre_get_posts`, code is executed before WordPress got its posts. There's access to `$query` but that's just for setting query variables, there are no posts retreived, and thus no `max_num_pages` to calculate from.

So that means I have no idea when I'm about to exceed max_num_pages.

I then copied the new code from `my_post_queries( $query )` to another function which hooks into `wp`. There, `max_num_pages` is a valid number and is_author() is correct too. As soon as I exceed the number of posts, still no luck. 404. I could set `$wp_query->is_404 = false` but that returns me to the index yet again.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: It's possible, but a bit tricky. Maybe AJAX pagination is an option for you? Anyway, [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1883/4771) might point you in a useful direction.

Comment: I have attempted to fix it using your answer but it did not work still. Details are in my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every page load, WordPress executes these functions in their respective order:

```
init();
parse_request($query_args);
send_headers();
query_posts();
handle_404();
register_globals();
```

where the main query is finished after `query_posts()`. Note that **in this point in time, WordPress knows the template AND all the query variables** like `max_num_pages`.

In `handle_404()`, if the *main query* has any posts, the function returns and WordPress continues to load the template. Else it sends a 404 HTTP status and loads the 404 template instead.

Since WordPress 4.5, there is a filter hook called `pre_handle_404`. If it's set to `true`, `handle_404()` returns (whether or not the *main query* has any posts!) and the template continues to load.

So after a **lot** of fiddling around, this finally works. Add this to your **functions.php**:

```
function ignore_404_past_max_page($bool = false, $query) {
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? intval(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
  if (is_author() && ($paged > $query->max_num_pages))
    $bool = true;
  return $bool;
}
add_filter( 'pre_handle_404', 'ignore_404_past_max_page', 10, 2);
```

That's it! No editing of existing functions, clean and does exactly what you'd want it to do: prevent WP from 404ing. Just make sure to **update WordPress to version 4.5** (and above)!

An unwanted side effect may be that now you can paginate untill `PHP_INT_MAX` and get empty pages (unless you add some `get_the_author_meta()` and `get_wp_user_avatar()` for example). You could probably memorize the maximum page number for each author in the database, then query it and compare it to `$paged` to set `$bool` to `false` in the function above. But I'm *really* happy with how it works now.